# I can't Scale or rotate in Blender 2.83

Tags: interface, transforms

I was working in a homework of my school and everything was working fine, but when I wanted add a new object, I couldn't rotate or scale, just move the object.

[image]

I think that accidentally I pressed a bottom and I activated a function or something, but I don't know I was searching in the program but I can't find the mistake.

In others projects I can work without problems. In the image, I'm trying to scale the circle, but I can't.

Thank you! I hope you can support me.

Comment: Typical reason for this is that the user has enabled "affect only locations".  Look on sidebar/tool/affect only; if locations is checked, uncheck it.

Comment: He also has Individual Origins selected in the Transform Pivot Point dropdown rather than Median Point. (To the right of 'Global' on the top toolbar.)

Comment: Thank you! I can solve the mistake.